# How can I prevent web fonts from being downloaded and used illegally?

Tags: fonts, font-face

I have a project where I am using an embedded font using `@font-face` in CSS. Everything is working fine but the site owner wants to encrypt the font so that no one can use it other than when viewed on the site.

How can that be setup? I have the font on the server, it's embedded using `@font-face` in CSS, but somehow I have to restrict the access to it.

Using a font hosting company is not an option, it has to be something that can be run locally on the server.

Answer (score 15):

If using a font hosting company is not an option, then you have to do all the work that the font hosting companies do yourself. This means securely delivering the font from your servers to the browser, making sure that the font file only contains enough information to allow the browser to render the type, preventing the end-user from downloading the font itself and using it locally, and obfuscating the font itself.

First up, make sure you have a license to use the font on the web. If you haven't got that, you're screwed.

After that, you'll want to ensure that your fonts are subsetted, so that they only include the characters your website needs to display. Then, you'll need to make sure that your fonts are obfuscated in such a way that the font is unusable on the desktop. [Font Squirrel's @font-face generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) can do both this and the previous step. Make sure you use the "Expert" mode to create your font kit, use their WebOnly™ protection and subset your font to include the characters.

Font Squirrel will also convert the fonts into EOT, OTF and WOFF files that will help your fonts to be used in the vast majority of modern browsers.

Finally, you should [ensure that your web server is configured to prevent hot linking](https://web.archive.org/web/20150210235516/http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1694/Prevent+hotlinking+with+a+.htaccess+file) to the font files themselves, preventing them from being requested from anywhere except your site.

Once you've taken those steps, you're about as far along as you can be. You'll want to make sure your font files are cacheable, but you'll need to strike a balance between cache performance and potentially storing files on the browser's cache for a long time. That's an exercise left to the reader.

**It's important to remember that even after you take all these steps, it is possible for people to download the altered font files and use them on the desktop with relative ease.** You can't prevent people from downloading the fonts and using them illegally in 100% of cases, but by taking these steps, you're further along the road to making sure you've done everything you can.

Comment: I agree. The original question is basically "how to implement DRM system for fonts" and the only correct answer is "DRM cannot exists". The reason is that DRM is about Alice sending a message to Bob without Eve getting a copy. And Bob and Eve are the same person (the one visiting the web page in this question)! So there's no way to transmit data to Bob without Eve also getting a copy. Every DRM system in existence is just smoke and mirrors to make Bob believe that he is not an alias for Eve. Some font licenses may require implementing some specific magic trick to pretend working DRM.

Comment: Mikko makes a great point, though the analogy is probably only understood by those who already knew what mikko was saying before reading the analogy. In a nutshell, a website is simply data sent over an HTTPS, the end user receives the data, and it is rendered by the browser, therefore, no matter what the end user gets the data. You have to assume that any copyrighted resource that you load to the web, will have its copyright infringed upon. Most every font at some point becomes available for free via P2P, or on Russian based websites.

Comment: Not all is lost though. The vast majority of websites frequented by people are sites that want to be a legitimate businesses, and at the time this was asked, there was no way of knowing if & where your font was being used illegally, however, today machine learning allows us to search the web using a glyph as the query. This allows font-designers to sue some of the people who infringed on there copyright. You can also choose to not license your font for web use. Its more about protecting your work, than it is the actual font file.

Comment: can you shed any light on how fontdue.com is going about preventing this from happening? i imagine it has something to do with the "new" cross origin policy?

Comment: I couldn't tell you exactly how fontdue.com is doing it, but I imagine they're using a combination of measures on the server, along with the HTTP header-based solutions, which could potentially inlcude CORS, CORP, COOP, etc. for clients that support it.