# How to protect my images & fonts when I upload my website on Github?

Tags: github

On my github website, I'm using a few images and fonts. The problem is that I don't want others to download these images or fonts (or link directly to their websites so that they can use them).

How do I prevent people from downloading them?

I've been searching for answers but I can't find an answer!

Edit: Just to add a bit more detail, in my CSS stylesheet, I'm linking my fonts like this.

```
@font-face tomato{
font-family: 'Tomato SC'; 
src: mywebsite.com/tomato-otf}
```

One problem is that people can just go to mywebsite.com/tomato-otf and download the font itself. I want to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

According to "[How can I prevent web fonts from being downloaded and used illegally?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13400304/6309)", this isn't really possible.
Especially when you consider that GitHub pages, through Jekyll, [does not suport `.htaccess`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26475499/6309), so you can't even [prevent hotlinking with a .htaccess file](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644230/prevent-hotlinking-with-a-htaccess-file).

At least, make sure your font has a license, and is subsetted, so that they only include the characters your website needs to display.