# Protect webfonts via Amazon CloudFront from download

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Is it possible to protect data embedded on my website via Amazon CloudFront from hotlinking or other downloads? I am mainly interested in protecting webfonts from being downloaded.

- Amazon CloudFront is connected to a S3 Bucket
- S3 Bucket Policy controls allowed domains for files via CloudFront

You think that could work?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have cloudfront setup connected to your s3 bucket, you can use Cloudfront [Signed Urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) to prevent download by anyone from the public.

You can put your fonts in a folder called fonts for example, and setup a separate behaviour in cloudfront for any path that contains `/fonts/` and in there you can activate `Restrict Viewer Access`.

[image]

In your website, you will need to add some way to generate the presigned url for this only when your webpage is loaded and you can put a short expiry time for this URL.

Comment: Thanks for taking part in this :) But is a signed url really needed when the access is allowed for that one domain only? The website user has no chance to download the file though having found the url, right?

Comment: If you had a nefarious user, they can technically grab that signed url and download the fonts on their browser if the expiry time is still valid. You can also download the font from the devtools. The above method will prevent hotlinking as they won't be able to generate the presigned url.

However, you can also serve the fonts directly from S3, and prevent hotlinking using the s3 bucket cors. You will bypass the cloudfront just for the fonts (but u will lose the advantage of CDN).

Comment: I've gone through the experience you are facing but with video files not fonts. And there is no way to totally prevent any download, but they are all steps to deter easy download.

For fonts though, some might use a font provider with a license that will handle the requests from font-face. I am not an expert on fonts, but I think this answer explains it better:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13400304/6828976

hope this helps @robinex

Comment: Thanks. But I can't download the fonts from devtools, when access is domain restricted, right? I have tried that already and the link was blocked. I could only serve the fonts on allowed domains. 

Or would you suggest to use [htaccess](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644230/prevent-hotlinking-with-a-htaccess-file) to be a better and easier solution?